# relation using orm rails two tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to print relations Emissions With trades.

**Example:**

-Trade 1

- Emission 1
- Emission 2

**Actuallly  my code print.**

-Trade 1

- Emission 1

-Trade 1

- Emission 2

**This code:**

```
        <% @emissions.group_by(&:trade).each do |trade, emission| %>
        <% emission.each do |e| %>
            <% if (e.users.present?) %>
                <li><%= trade.name %></li>
                    <ul>
                        <li><%= e.name %></li>
                    </ul>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
        </li>
    <% end %>
```

**UPDATE**

The list should appear if the user relationship is associated with the emission.
For instance:
       <% If (e.users.present?)%>

<% = emission.name%>

This is only displayed if the emission ratio with the user exists.

The company name should appear if this relationship exists.

Try the following
       <% If (emission.users.present?)%>

<% = trade.name%>

<% = emission.name%>

But this does nothing but repeat twice for each issue the company name.

Comment: If a trade has two emissions, and one of them has a user, should the trade name be displayed?  Should any of the emissions relating to that trade by displayed?

Comment: If the user only has a related emission to display the company name.
If you have n emissions also the company name shown.
If the user has no associated emissions nothing is displayed.

Comment: When you say "the user" do you mean the person viewing the page?  I don't see anything in your code about `current_user` or something.

Comment: yes,   defined in application_controller, user = User.find(current_user.id)

Comment: Your code doesn't refer to `user` either.  Also that bit of code `user = User.find(current_user.id) ` looks odd - why not just say `user = current_user`, or not bother and just refer to `current_user` in the first place?

Comment: Exactly it might be a good solution.
I am new to rails as could implement in my code?

Comment: Sorry, i don't know what you are asking me.  Also i still don't understand your requirements.  You have not listed what the relationship between a User, Trade and Emission is and you have not clearly stated what should happen in relation to the current_user and the view code.

Comment: Simple, if there is a relationship user show emission associated emissions and the company name.

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation is all over the place and you have lots of html tags which have an `<% end %>` in the middle, and stuff like that, so it's a bit confusing, but i think that you're trying to do something like this:

```
<% @emissions.group_by(&:trade).each do |trade, grouped_emissions| %>
  <li><%= trade.name %>
  <ul>
    <% grouped_emissions.each do |emission| %>
      <% if (emission.users.present?) %>
        <li><%= e.name %></li>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Exactly Awesome.
Exactly, awesome.
But there is a problem, the company name should appear if the user has is related to the emission.
Try to include it in <% if (emission.users.present?)%> But the company appears duplicated.

Comment: When you say "company" do you mean "trade"?  Can you please edit your question and clearly specify the requirements for when the trade/company name should and should not be displayed?